# Overloading ! operator in VB to be used in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, operator-overloading

I have a VB class called `Filter` where I implemented several operators. One of which is the `Not` Operator:

```vb
Public MustInherit Class Filter(Of T)

    Public Shared Operator Not(filter As Filter(Of T)) As Filter(Of T)
        Return new NotFilter(Of T)(filter))
    End Operator

    ' other operators..

    Public MustOverride Function filters(o As T) As Boolean
End Class

Public Class NotEmptyFilter 
    Inherits Filter(Of String)

    Public Overrides Function filters(o As String) As Boolean
        Return o.Length > 0;
    End Function

End Class
```

Now I want to use this code in several other projects which are written in C#. I have no difficulties using the `Or` operator as the `|` operator, but I can't use the `Not` operator as the `!` operator like follows:

```
Filter<string> isEmptyFilter = !(new NotEmptyFilter());
```

as I get the following compiler error:

> `Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'Filter<string>'`

Does anybody know how to fix this issue? Bonus points for an explaination as to why this is not working.

PS: I did not set these projects up like that and there is nothing I can change about it. Legacy code..

Comment: So what happens with what you've already got? Is it not recognized at all in C#, or does something odd happen?

Comment: @JonSkeet compiler error. I added the message

Comment: I wonder if it’s the `~` operator?

Comment: Can you show your C# code? Is Operator Not a member of a generic class?

Comment: @Ryan odd. That does seem to work. I don't really find it that aesthetically pleasing tbh as I would use the `!` operator for boolean operations and i never use the `~` anywhere else

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd provide a [mcve] of this - I'd like to look at the generated IL, but as someone with limited VB, it'll take me longer than I'd like to reproduce this, compared with a complete sample.

Comment: Mmmm... looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/operator-statement, it looks like basically VB is missing a unary operator compared with C# :(

Comment: I was able to create a operator! in C# that works, but I need your surrounding code to know why yours doesn't.

Comment: @Ryan thanks for the duplicate link! That was exactly my problem!

Comment: @NetMage did you create the operator in VB and then use it in a C# project? If so, I will create a MCV for you

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right. Thanks for the link. I guess you don't need a MCV any more?

Comment: I don't need one, although I think the question would be better with one :) On the other hand, as it's a dupe, it may not be worth it.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right. Added the MCV ps: too late

Comment: @LonelyNeuron No, I didn't understand that from your question the first time. But someday when we get extensions everything you would be able to create an extension operator! in C# that calls the VB operator Not. Someday.